# Text area length calculation not working properly in html

Tags: jquery, html, textarea

hi i have a text area in my html page and i am using span tag to show its length

**html code:**

```
<textarea cols="50" rows="10" maxlength="160"  id="main_text"></textarea><br/>
<span class="charno">0</span>/160
```

and i am using some jquery to show the length in span tag

**jquery code:**

```
$("#main_text").keyup(function(){
      $(".charno").html($("#main_text").val().length);
});
```

**My problem is:**

- when i enter 160 characters in the textarea without pressing ENTER
  button in keyboard it shows correct result(160/160).
- But when i use ENTER button 1 time inside the textarea, i can able to enter 159 characters only(159/160).
- when i use ENTER button 2 times inside the textarea, i can able to enter 158 characters only(158/160).
- when i use ENTER button 3 times inside the textarea, i can able to enter 157 characters only(157/160).
- and so on....

is there any problem in my code or am i doing anything wrong 
please help.........

Comment: Testing your code gave me the exact opposite, pressing enter added a char to the count.  http://jsfiddle.net/CGfmN/

Comment: i don't see any problem like you mentioned working fine

Comment: hey its working perfectly http://jsfiddle.net/55FMQ/ just opposite to your question

Comment: Since, the `maxlength` of textarea is 160, so after that any input won't work. Even a `Enter` key press.

Comment: guys i had did some edits in my problem see it

Comment: it could be because of `\r\n` new line representation in a windows system

Comment: Everything seems to work fine. What do you want to achieve with the above code?

Answer (score 1):

This is because one enter key is equivalent to 2 alphanumeric keys entered in text area.
If you put "enter key" for 5 times out of 160 characters then you can enter 150 more characters.(150(alphanumeric)+ 10(5*2 for enter key)= 160 characters)

But while counting the "enter key" using length it will return only one.

Comment: well thanks vikram for understanding my problem is there any solution for this.....

Comment: In this case Yon can't set maxlength using html. AS it wouldn't allow you entering all characters because of enter key. Try restricting user for maxlength using JS.
Here is some sample code
$("#main_text").on("keydown", function(e){
var len =  1 + this.value.length-this.value.split("\n").length;
if(len > 160){
return false;
}
});

Answer (score 0):

It should count 1 for enter, if still its taking enter as length 2 please use following trick

```
$("#main_text").keyup(function(e){
var code = e.keyCode;

if (code == 13)
{

var code = e.keyCode;

var l = $("#main_text").val().length;

$(".charno").html(l-1)
}
$(".charno").html($("#main_text").val().length);
});
```